Protecting workbook using openpyxl
I am trying to protect an excel workbook using openpyxl.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("/path/raw_data.xlsx")
wb.security = WorkbookProtection()
wb.security.workbookPassword = 'password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True
wb.save("/path/protected_raw_data.xlsx")

So far, my code has boiled down to this. I don't get any errors and the new protected_raw_data.xlsx file gets created but there is no protection on the workbook when I open it. Does openpyxl only protect new workbooks and not existing workbooks? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Openpyxl only allows adding protection to prevent accidental modification of the worksheets. You cannot password protect a workbook i.e. have Excel request a password on opening the work book. You would need to use a module that uses Excel for that like Xlwings and Win32com. Does not matter if its a existing or new workbook.

The protection you have added is Workbook Protection, (Excel Menu Option Review --> Protect Workbook). This provides protection to prevent other users from viewing hidden worksheets, adding, moving, deleting, or hiding worksheets, and renaming worksheets as stated in the docs. You can also apply Worksheet Protection, (Excel Menu Option Review --> Protect Sheet).

I am using Linux so xlwings will not work and pywin32 is not available for me in my company's repo. The way I am using openpyxl is creating a new workbook, but the Worksheet Protection aspect (Excel Menu Option Review --> Protect Workbook) is not working.

Check Spire.XLS for Python module (paid): https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.XLS-for-Python/Program-Guide/Security/Python-Protect-or-Unprotect-Excel-Files.html
